# detect when element is added to a custom elements

Tags: javascript, html, events

I want to detect if an element is added (or removed) from a custom element. For example, consider the following custom element

```
<x-foo>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</x-foo>
```

Now I can simply add an element

```
document.querySelector('x-foo').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
```

Is there for example a lifecycle callback method (like there is for attribute changes) to detect this ?

Comment: A lifecycle what now? There are mutation events / observers, but aren't you the one that is adding the elements, and wouldn't you know when you're adding elements in your own code.

Comment: I got it from [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/). There is this 'attributeChangedCallback' mutation event, so I thought there might as well be an event for this.

Comment: That's all experimental and doesn't really work anywhere.

Comment: true, absolutely experimental! but it works in chrome 34. And with a polyfill it works everywhere :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `element.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(){})` and `element.attachEvent("onpropertychange", function(){})` but it not working on all browsers..

Answer (score 1):

What's super cool is that you can listen for insertions with css animations. Just add an imperceptible css animation with a finite duration, and then listen for its start. Doing this, you're not listening to all DOMNodeInserted events on the element (or even worse, the whole document). You will handle only events during which a div is appended to x-foo.

This technique is really great when you've got many different things being appended to the parent... For example, it'd be great for listening for the addition of a div with a certain class.

**1) Add CSS**

Add very short, unnoticable animation to the elements whose insertion you want to listen for.

**Note:** you must prefix your css

```
<style>
  x-foo > div {
      animation-duration: 0.001s;
      animation-name: nodeInserted;
  }

  @keyframes nodeInserted {  
    from { opacity: 0.99; }
    to { opacity: 1; }  
  }
</style>
```

**2) JS - Declare handler** - the callback

```
var nodeInsertedListener = function(event){
    if (event.animationName == "nodeInserted") {
        var node = event.target;
        // call handler on new div
        xfooHasNewDivHandler(node); // defined in next step
    }
}
```

**3) JS - Define handler body** - callback body whose code is to execute when a div is added to x-foo.
You could have also added this directly to the handler

```
function xfooHasNewDivHandler(div) {
  div.style.color = 'red';

  //x-foo-has-new-div stuff...
}
```

**4) Register event listeners** - tell the document to listen out for animations' start

```
['', 'MS', 'webkit'].forEach(function(prefix) {
    var animEvtName = "AnimationStart";

    prefix || (animEvtName = animEvtName.toLowerCase()), 
              (animEvtName = prefix+animEvtName);

    document.addEventListener(prefix+animEvtName, nodeInsertedListener, false);
});
```

**I think this method wicked cool, and hope it helps anyone reading.**

Answer (score 0):

[DOMNodeInserted is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) and removed from standard, you should use [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), its [support is pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver).

```
var parent = document.querySelector('x-foo');
var number_of_nodes = parent.childNodes.length;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (parent.childNodes.length > number_of_nodes) {
       number_of_nodes = parent.childNodes.length;
       console.log('element added');
    }
});
observer.observe(parent, {childList: true});
```

to stop listening you need to call `observer.disconnect();`